# centrally two button not looking good blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing one app in which I want to create two buttons. These buttons should be `center` aligned custom buttons with bitmap fill backgrounds. Each should also contain text that is centered in that button.

The problem is that those two buttons are not set properly. The second button is gone behind the first and its bitmap height is also decreased compared to the first button.

For both custom buttons I have the same CustomButton class.

**Here is code:**

```
 CustomButtonField aboutM1 = new CustomButtonField(0,"About G1",registerbg,registerbg,Field.FOCUSABLE,0x324F85);
                    add(new RichTextField(Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));

                  //  CustomButtonField2 ForgotPass = new CustomButtonField2("Forgot Password?",0x324F85);
                    CustomButtonField ForgotPass = new CustomButtonField(0,"Forgot Password?",registerbg,registerbg,Field.FOCUSABLE,0x324F85);

                    add(new RichTextField(Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));

                    VerticalFieldManager bottomVFM = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
                    HorizontalFieldManager bottomHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER);

                    bottomHFM.add(aboutM1);
                    bottomHFM.add(ForgotPass);
                    bottomVFM.add(bottomHFM);
                    add(bottomVFM);
```

**Custom Button:**

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;

public class CustomButtonField extends Field
{
    Bitmap Unfocus_img, Focus_img, current_pic;
    int width;
    String text;
    Font font;   
    int custColor;
    CustomButtonField(int width, String text, Bitmap onFocus, Bitmap onUnfocus, long style,int custColor)
    {
        super(style);
        Unfocus_img = onUnfocus;
        Focus_img = onFocus;
        current_pic = onFocus;
        this.text = text;
        this.width = width;
        this.custColor = custColor;
    }
    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setExtent(current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight());        
    }
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        try
        {
                FontFamily fntFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Sans");
                font = fntFamily.getFont(Font.BOLD,20);              
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            font = Font.getDefault();

        }
        graphics.setFont(font);


        graphics.setColor(custColor); 

        int xText = (getWidth() - font.getAdvance(text)) / 2;
        int yText = (getHeight() - font.getHeight()) / 2;

        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight(), current_pic , 0 , 0);
        graphics.drawText(text, xText, yText);

       /* graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, current_pic.getWidth(), current_pic.getHeight(), current_pic , 0 , 0);
        graphics.drawText(text, width , 7);*/
        graphics.setDrawingStyle(Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER, true);
    }
    protected void onFocus(int direction) 
    {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        current_pic = Unfocus_img;
        this.invalidate();
    }
  protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
  {

    }
    protected void onUnfocus() 
    {
        super.onUnfocus();
        current_pic = Focus_img;
        invalidate();
    }
    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return true;
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are using a Bitmap as your ButtonField background. And the width and height of the ButtonField is dependent on the Bitmap rather than the length of text. You need to decide what you want to do when the text length exceeds the default width of background Bitmap provided. So, please specify what is your decision regarding long text.

Comment: come on ... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java

Comment: As you said on response of the code, https://gist.github.com/3215389 (on chat room), you need to stretch the background image. If you need a complete implementation, you can knock me here. There were several post in SO regarding implementation of Custom `ButtonField`.

Comment: Did you tried `Background` object for setting background of your CustomButtonField. You can create several types of background (image background) using `BackgroundFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you used is correct , the only drawback is that you are centering your text according to your bitmap width & text length is more than bitmap width . 
You may need to change your approach . 
Have a look on Blackberry UI samples in this below URL & check for EmbossedButtonField Demo

```
https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java
```

Its a good approach to create a custom button , once we are not sure by the button label length.

Comment: it is good example according to me but problem is that how can i stretch the bitmap...

Comment: what you need to do , you need to use two bitmaps . for focus and unfocus. This bitmap will be divided into three parts start , mid and end part.
According to text length mid part will be drawn many times (by using loop ) as per text length using graphics.drawBitmap , hence it will accomplish your resize bitmap issue.